# How to sum up multiple table tr td data values to one field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to sum all table tr td values into one field i.e. Total Debit Amount using jquery. But, when I am adding a new row dynamically to the table, old table tr td data is getting replaced by new row data which is added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA9Tj.png)

Below is my jquery function code :

```
var total_debit_amount = $('#debit_amount').val();
$("#tbody").on("keyup", "input[name^=amtDebit]", function() {
  //$("tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
  $("tbody tr:not(:first-child)").each(function() {
    var cell_debit_amt = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) input').val();
    //alert(search);
    if (total_debit_amount = 0) {
      total_debit_amount = cell_debit_amt + 0;
    } else {
      total_debit_amount = total_debit_amount + cell_debit_amt;
    }
    $('#debit_amount').val(total_debit_amount);
  });
  //});          
});
```

Can anyone suggest what is missing or wrong in the code.

Comment: `if (total_debit_amount = 0) {` -> `if (total_debit_amount === 0) {` each row, you're *resetting* the total to 0 with `total_debit_amount = 0`.  You do want to reset it (which you're missing), but once, just before the `$("tbody tr").each` loop

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector `#tbody` requires an ID to be set on a `div`, `table` or `tbody` element, otherwise the `.on()` event delegation will never happen. I actually changed the `keyup` event to `input` as this will also respond to mouse pasting events.

```js
$("#tbody").on("input", "input[name^=amtDebit]", function(){
 $("#debit_amount").val( $("input[name^=amtDebit]").get().reduce((a,c)=>+c.value+a,0) )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td>Voucher No.<br>
<input type="text" name="vouchno"></td><td>
Payment Date<br>
<input type="date" name="date"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Total Debit Amount<br>
<input type="text" name="debitamnt" id="debit_amount"></td><td>
Payment Total Credit Amount<br>
<input type="text" name="creditamnt"></td></tr>
</table>
<table id="tbody"><tr><th>Line No.</th><th>Ledger Name</th><th>Amount Debit</th><th>Amount Credit</th><th>Remove</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger1" value="Cash"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtDebit1" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtCredit1" value="0"></td>
<td><button>remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger2"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtDebit2" value="500"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtCredit2" value="0"></td>
<td><button>remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger3"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtDebit3" value="200"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="amtCredit3" value="0"></td>
<td><button>remove</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Instead of writing a lengthy code in the callback function I reverted to using an `Array.reduce()` method to sum up the relevant fields.

**Update:**

You can shorten the script even further and make it start after the first row by applying `Array.prototype.slice()` and doing something like this:

```js
["amtDebit","amtCredit"].forEach(sel=>
 $("#tbody").on("input", `input[name^=${sel}]`,_=>
  $(`#${sel}`).val( $(`input[name^=${sel}]`).get().slice(1).reduce((a,c)=>+c.value+a,0))));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table><tr><td>Voucher No.<br><input type="text" name="vouchno"></td><td>Payment Date<br><input type="date" name="date"></td></tr><tr><td>Total Debit Amount<br><input type="text" name="debitamnt" id="amtDebit"></td><td>Payment Total Credit Amount<br><input type="text" name="creditamnt" id="amtCredit"></td></tr></table><table id="tbody"><tr><th>Line No.</th><th>Ledger Name</th><th>Amount Debit</th><th>Amount Credit</th><th>Remove</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger1" value="Cash"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtDebit1" value="0"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtCredit1" value="0"></td><td><button>remove</button></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger2"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtDebit2" value="500"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtCredit2" value="0"></td><td><button>remove</button></td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="ledger3"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtDebit3" value="200"></td><td><input type="number" name="amtCredit3" value="0"></td><td><button>remove</button></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Bro what If I have to skip first row values from this table in that keyup function??

Comment: How to write for Amount Credit. When I have written for Amount Credit it is adding debit amount also which is wrong

Comment: Okay will check ur latest comments... How to write on change on those total debit amount & total credit amount .. i tried many ways but its not working